# How to prevent thymeleaf from replacing special characters in HTML attribute values?

Tags: template-engine, thymeleaf

I'am using Thymeleaf in combination with a js micro-templating routine, which result in special characters in attribute values. When running Thymeleaf on

```
<a style="display:<%= x ? 'block' : 'none' %>;">
```

it creates

```
<a style="display:&lt;%= x ? &#39;block&#39; : &#39;none&#39; %&gt;;">
```

while I would expect to get exactly the same I put into the processor.
How do I use special characters in HTML attribute values?
Many thanks!

Comment: A solution is to extend the template writer for this puprose. There is no setting to configure the serialization behavior for attributes. For me it remains unclear why attribute values of non-thymeleaf attributes are encoded.

Answer (score 13):

Try to play with

```
th:utext="#{unescaped text}">
```

See Thymeleaf doc [Unescaped Text](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#unescaped-text)

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to to insert a chunk of html into a template using <th:block th:text="${fooHtmlChunk}"></th:block> and was going crazy trying to figure out why the fooHtmlChunk html was encoded! Using th:utext instead of th:text was exactly my issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is some variants to review:

- use `LEGACYHTML5` option in `templateResolver` as mentioned above
- override `template` method in Underscore.js

I prefer second approach. Place this code in your initialization script:

```
var original = _.template;
_.template = function(content) {
    // fix operators escaped by Thymeleaf HTML5 validator
    content = content.replace(/&#39;/g, "'");
    content = content.replace(/&lt;/g, "<");
    content = content.replace(/&gt;/g, ">");
    return original.call(this, content);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to surround your code with a CDATA block.

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp

Comment: CDATA blocks are at least uncommon in attribute values. Also I use HTML not XHTML and if I could use CDATA blocks I would need to remove the respective markup before interpreting the template.

Comment: 404 not found for the link

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the other template modes but I know html5 and xml are not going to let you do this since the document thymeleaf would be generating would NOT validate against the doctype. So at least in those modes, I don't think this is possible. (Maybe with a custom dialect?)

So why the desire to use two templating tools on the same page anyway?

Comment: We are using a two-phase templating approach, server and client. The way thymeleaf integrates with an html page is helpful in this scenario. We would also switch to another, more appropriate templating solution, but did not find one yet. A custom dialect would have been a solution to, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As hubbardr already suggested, using LEGACYHTML5 as template mode might help you here.

Comment: Agreed, but the favored HTML5 dialect expects strict XHTML syntax and wasn't therefore useful for us when we faced the above issue. In my opinion it's rather a bug in the template writer. Where is the point to touch attribute value of non-thymeleaf attributes.